# Do imperatives trigger reflexive pronouns in Latin?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, imperative, reflexive-pronoun

In English, imperative verbs have "invisible subjects": syntactically, they act like there's an invisible pronoun in the subject position. This is why we see *look closely at **yourself*** instead of **look closely at **you***, even though there's no other "you" in the sentence to trigger the reflexive.

Is the same true in Latin?

(Most instances of imperatives I can think of are in the second person, and Latin doesn't mark the second-person reflexive—but third-person imperatives do exist, and it seems plausible that some grammarian might have specified whether they should be followed by *sē* or *eum*.)

Comment: The imperative implies "you", however rudely, "you" are the receiver of the command: "(You) do it!". In English, imperatives are often used rudely, inviting aggression, was this the case in Latin? The (English) use of "yourself", it is more polite than "You!". Use this here when addressing colleagues, strangers; whom, are invariably better at Latin than I, people like yourself as opposed to people like you! Demonstrative pronouns may be required if a target is identified: "(You) kill him!", sort of thing.

Comment: @tony The imperative in Latin wasn't particularly rude or aggressive; it was often used in prayers, for example.

Comment: Would you consider the *ipsum* in *te ipsum* a reflexive? Semantically, it seems to play the same role as the "-self" in "yourself". As the imperative is more common with the second person, studying *ipsum/ipsos* might give more than studying *se*.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: A form of "ipse" is used to emphasise a reflexive pronoun, functioning as an intensifier e.g. "dixit se ipsum venturum esse" = "He said that he himself would come".

Comment: @tony I know, but in the second person that pronoun seems to be the closest to a reflexive we have. That's why I asked whether it'd count instead of assuming so. For example, *nosce te ipsum* would be "know yourself".

Comment: I don't have any evidence, but it seems obvious to me that e.g. "Let him praise himself" would have to be *laudato se* rather than *laudato eum* (which would mean "Let him praise him=someone else"). Is there a language that has distinct reflexive pronouns but doesn't use them with imperatives?

Comment: @TKR Not that I know of, but I know very few languages well enough to say for sure. I asked about that on Linguistics.SE, and nobody seemed to know of one, but I don't have any specific evidence of absence.

Comment: Joonas llmavirta: Does "nosce te ipsum" answer Draconis's Q?